# "fatal: corrupt patch at line XX" when staging single line

Tags: git, git-gui

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to stage a single line or multiple lines using the git gui (right click -> stage lines for commit). It's not the first time it occure to me, and I've found others facing it.However I couldn't find how to solve it.

Did any one ever encountered this problem? is there something I can do (staging all the file is not a real solution)

**Update:**
Here is a file which gives me the following error when I try to stage the deleted line.

```
@@ -1,7 +1,6 @@
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:src="@drawable/texture"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
-   android:dither="true"
    >
</bitmap>
\ No newline at end of file
```

Here is the error message:

```
fatal: corrupt patch at line 14
```

strangely the following fine doesn't even have 14 line!? note ending file with a new line didn't solve the problem

Comment: Can you paste the lines you're trying to stage? Specifically, are you trying to stage a patch with "No newline at end of file"? C.f. [this thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/BUG-git-apply-sometimes-says-quot-corrupt-patch-quot-when-adding-single-lines-td5434443.html)

Comment: It as nothing to do with a specific line but, there is some line after which a single line cannot be staged, I currently don't have this problem.I'll try to post, something when I face it again

Answer (score 46):

Apparently Git GUI [*requires* that files end with a newline when staging individual lines](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Bug-in-Git-Gui-Creates-corrupt-patch-td2384251.html).

I'm pretty sure that at at least one point in time, staging individual lines was ok even without a newline at the end of the file, but apparently that's no longer possible. Just ran into this problem myself, having newlines at the end of the file fixes it, and removing them causes it.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, there are some line that I can stage and other that I can not (in the same file), I some characters might cause this, but I don't know which,

Comment: Adding the newline didn't work for me, but an interesting idea that I assume works sometimes.

Comment: Just experienced this problem too. Adding the newline didn't work for me either but in any case there is `git add -p -- <file>`.

Comment: I'm going to test this first time that this occurs

Comment: This didn't work at first for me in Git GUI, there was something storing that there wasn't originally a newline in the file ("\ No newline at end of file" showing in the preview window). Once I manually did the changes to the file and committed it, then that same file was able to do the single line stage/unstage again (the "\ No newline at end of file" was gone).

Comment: fixed it in my case (just copied a patch from an email in a file and did not have a newline at the end. Adding it fixed it (used git command line)

Comment: To those who comment saying this doesn't work: you won't be able to patch this file using `git gui` _until after_ you add the newline to the end of the file, _and commit it_. Once it's committed with the newline, you can patch it again.

Comment: Can confirm what @DrewNoakes said. That's exactly how it behaves for me as well. This post is the correct answer. For reference: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/BUG-git-apply-sometimes-says-quot-corrupt-patch-quot-when-adding-single-lines-td5434443.html

Comment: For a temporary workaround (until you get to the part where you want to commit the chunk with the newline) the answer by Zonko may help.

Comment: Adding a new line solved it for me as well

Answer (score 16):

Actually, this often happens when you edit '-' lines.
**When you remove '-' and forget to add ' ' (space) instead of it**

Or, by mistake, you add two spaces and you use 'tabs' as identation

Open your patch and check that all lines you want to leave untouched are started with ' ' (one space)

I have saw that some people use `--ignore-space-change` `--ignore-whitespace` `--whitespace=fix` as workaround but this is another thing you must not mix into.

Open your patch and check that all lines you want to leave untouched are started with ' ' (space)

**UPD**

it also possible your editor has option: "Delete spaces at end line"
So, when you in your editor save patch:

```
-Line with space at end <--- NOTICE: Here one space at the end
+Line with no space at end<--- Here no space
```

Your editor remove trailing space and patch become like this:

```
-Line with space at end<--- Here no space. Patch will FAIL!!!
+Line with no space at end<--- Here no space also
```

This patch will FAIL because origin file has no line:

```
-Line with space at end<---
```

it has:

```
-Line with space at end <---
```

**UPD2**

So if in your patch in next line

```
android:tileMode="repeat"
```

Your editor remove trainling space. Patch will FAIL

Answer (score 2):

Git GUI fails to add/remove lines from the index when the chunk you are working with is too big (i.e. too many successive lines modified).

My workaround : if the changes are not a "wall of pink" (if there are some unmodified lines in the middle of the chunk), go to edit > options and reduce the number of lines in the context of diffs. If this doesn't work, you are screwed ; use an other tool (like the command line for instance).

Comment: Worked for me. I was actually able to stage lines everywhere except the last chunk, which was rather big (some 50 lines I think) and also had the no-newline-problem described by Kyle. By setting the number of lines of context to 1, the stuff i wanted to stage got moved into the second to last chunk so I was able to stage it.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error while staging hunks.

The "whitespace" mentioned here reminded me that I have, in my git diff options, "-w", which skips white-space while diffing.

I removed that flag (using git-gui's "Options..."), and was able to stage hunks without the error.  I then added it back (because I usually don't want to see whitespace diffs when examining what has changed).

Not sure this will help you but it's rather harmless to try and easy to undo.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by kyl191's answer I came up with a simple solution for this problem:

1. add newline character to the end of your file
2. stash all changes

   ```
   git stash
   ```
3. add newline character to the end of your file once again, so you have a newline character in your current file as well as in your stashed version
4. stage the corresponding hunk (contains just your newline)

   ```
   git stage <your file>
   ```
5. pop your changes from stash

   ```
   git stash pop
   ```

Now you should be able to stage single lines via gui without this error. This works because after you staged just the newline containing part, the diff to the version recovered from stash already sees a file wich ends with a newline character.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I tried to add a newline to my patch in emacs and it automatically removed the newline at the end again when I saved it.

If you're using emacs to add a newline to the end of your patch, it may also be removing it again. I opened another text editor to add my newline and it worked.